# How can i migrate data from one Couchbase server(localhost) to another server(34.xx.xxx.xx)

Tags: java, couchbase

I am newbee to couchbase server,I want to transfer my buckets from one data cocuhbase server to another server. i am explored some, i find the **cbimport** & **cbexport**  which are used to migrate inside the Cluster .Any idea , thanks in advance

@Cricker_007

[image: Error faced while doing XCDR Replicaton]

Comment: How about you enable the XDC Replication? Or if you simply add a new Node, the data replicates on its own

Comment: https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.6/xdcr/xdcr-intro.html

Comment: @ cricket_007 , Above is th error when i try to do XDCR replicaiton ,??

Comment: Auth failure... Sounds like a permission issue, so that's something on your end

Answer (score 0):

You can try **cbtools**

> The cbtransfer tool is used to transfer data between clusters and
>   to/from files.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/admin/CLI/cbtransfer_tool.html

Comment: When i try to execute this command cbtransfer http://5x.x9.1x7.2xx:8091 http://localhost:8091 -b LotusNotesDATA --bucket-destination killerD , it shows the ** error: SASL auth socket error: 172.17.0.2:11210, user: LotusNotesDATA **